requests module is not found in pySpark - running in Jupyter on Kubernetes
File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
import(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Also, just pasting the error message is not a good way to ask questions. Please see how to ask questions on StackOverflow.
